# "un cocktail détonnant" vs "un cocktail détonant"

Tags: expressions

> C'est un **cocktail détonnant** de deux personnes avec l'expérience de la finance et de la technologie mobile.

I usually use "*détonnant*" to figuratively refer to "*an unharmonious/clashing combination*", as shown in the example above.

Then again, if you have the idea of "*an explosive combination*" in mind, as in "*cobble together an explosive combination of rock and electropop*", can you also say "*C'est un **cocktail détonant** de* ..." in French? The same goes for "*un **mélange détonant***" vs "*un **mélange détonnant***".

Answer (score 2):

From where I see it, as soon as you're speaking about 1 thing, not compared to another (cocktail, recipe, people,...), the people will understand "détonant" (=> Explosif). Actually even in your example, I think it should have been détonant :

> C'est un cocktail détonant de deux personnes avec l'expérience de la finance et de la technologie mobile.

Meaning it's a mix that will explode, in the positive sense like "The sales explode" and not like "Dynamite explodes".

Looking at the [ngram for détonnant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=D%C3%A9tonnant&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9tonnant%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9tonnant%3B%2Cc1) we see it's not use quite as much as [détonant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9tonant&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9tonant%3B%2Cc0). I was suprised to see a raising usage in the past 20 or 30 years so I looked it a bit further and the [search results for 1990-2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%C3%A9tonnant%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:2008,lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=4JULXbndEoLTwQKYhJKIDw&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwi5zbe9oPjiAhWCaVAKHRiCBPEQ8NMDCHM&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1), made me realize that in all of these examples, "détonnant" was wrongly used instead of "détonant".

So my advise would be to be very careful when using this word, and be conscious that most people will only understand it as "explosif", whatever the spelling with 1 or 2 "n". In spoken language the ambiguity is of course even stronger.

Comment: That sentence randomly picked online might not have been the best example, then. At any rate, in saying the following myself, I'd still use "détonnant". What's your take on this? "*C’est un **cocktail détonnant** de sport et d'art floral.*"

Comment: Il n'y a rien d'étonnant à cette confusion courante entre *détonant* et *détonnant*. Le *tonnerre* qui *tonne* (latin *tonare*...) ou *détone* n'aide pas.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it would be really confusing.

However, you can say "*un cocktail explosif*" which is the same as "*un cocktail détonant*" ie "*an explosive combination*". It's the usual idiome

ref: https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/cocktail+explosif.html

Answer (score 1):

The verb **détonner** means **sing off key**, it comes from the word **ton** (**tone** in english). So it's a mistake to use it in this case.

The verb **détoner** comes from **détonation**, in english it could be translated as **They rock !**

So in your example it's a mistake to use **détonnant** because it means that it's a bad duo (unless it was what the author wanted to say)

Comment: I agree the example is probably a mistake, but it doesn't necerssarily mean it's a bad duo. It could be a duo which is not in the tone of other duos. To take a music example : "Les white Stripes sont un groupe détonnant" could mean they're different (of other bands) because they only consist of 1 drummer and 1 guitar player, while using "détonant" would mean they're full of energy.

Answer (score 0):

> **Mélange détonant**, mélange de gaz qui peuvent exploser en se combinant ; se dit de personnes dont les oppositions peuvent se
>   traduire par des crises violentes ; se dit de choses qui, réunies,
>   peuvent provoquer une crise, un problème grave. ([Larousse en
>   ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9tonant/24823?q=d%C3%A9tonant#24706))

C'est connoté négativement il me semble donc non je n'emploierais pas « cocktail détonant » pour traduire « an explosive combination of rock and electropop », même en remplaçant « mélange » par « [cocktail](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocktail#Fran%C3%A7ais) » qui par extension veut dire *mélange* de toutes façons. D'autre part comme on l'a remarqué dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37098), bien des emplois de *détonnant* s'expliquent par l'erreur orthographique et ont pour valeur le sens de *détonant*.

En ce qui me concerne, je n'emploie jamais le participe présent du verbe *détonner* en adjectif (*détonnant*) pour le sens au figuré de *ce qui n'est pas en harmonie avec* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9tonner)) ou *qui n'est pas dans le ton général* ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9tonner)) ; le TLFi réfère à détonnant comme ce « qui sort de l'intonation » et on a un exemple avec des voix et ça ne ressemble pas à un emploi au figuré, mais spécialisé ; je dis plutôt qu'une chose *détonne* ou que *ça détonne*. Autrement j'emploierais peut-être l'adjectif [*bigarré*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bigarr%C3%A9) pour qualifier l'« ensemble d’éléments disparates et tranchants qui manque d’harmonie » (Wiktionnaire). Avec un sens plus neutre je parlerais sans doute d'un « mélange [*hétéroclite*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A9t%C3%A9roclite) », pour un « mélangé d'éléments disparates » (Wiktionnaire).

Pour revenir à l'« explosive combination of rock and electropop », à mon avis il ne faut pas se fier au fait qu'on y voit facilement l'adjectif *explosif* en français et on n'a pas expliqué ce qu'on voudrait dire exactement en anglais ici. En français l'adjectif peut avoir le sens de ce qui *se manifeste violemment, instantanément ou brusquement* (voir [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/explosif)) ou de [*sensationnel*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/explosif) (voir [sensationnel](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sensationnel/72094?q=sensationnel#71293) au Larousse en ligne) mais je ne suis pas certain que c'est ce sens que l'on exprime dans la phrase en langue anglaise où l'on donne pour le terme au figuré le sens « [shocking, startling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explosive) », à moins que ce ne soit une métaphore sur le thème de « having the character of an explosion » (Wiktionnaire). Avec *startling* je pense à *stupéfiant, époustouflant, renversant* etc. Ce pourrait être simplement le haut degré de surprise, *(très) surprenant*, voire [*haut en couleurs*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/haut_en_couleur), je n'en suis pas certain mais je trouve que de présumer qu'*explosive* signifie directement « explosif » est périlleux en contexte.